# Force the Refresh Page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to do a forced refresh of my page when I visit it. Basically when I go to the shopping cart page (/cart) and visit it for the first time some of the cost data is incorrect, but if I reload the page it becomes correct. So I would like to set that if I visit (my visitors visit) the page it automatically refreshes. How is this possible?

I tried this code:

```
<?php $refresh = 'Yes'; // lets assume the refresh condition is yes  
if(isset($refresh) &&  $refresh == 'Yes'){ // or simply you can check by isset only no need to check for $refresh == 'Yes'
         header("Location:current_page.php");
         $refresh= false; // if you don't want to refresh the page again without any condition comes true.
         } 
?>
```

Comment: This seems like the wrong way to fix your problem. What's actually going on *with the code* that's creating the incorrect cost? Why not fix that instead of forcing a refresh?

Comment: @disinfor Because the error is caused by a bug in the Woocommerce Deposits plugin, which I was not able to solve. (I know that is the wrong way to fix my problem, but for now is enough).